# Hash Map (int, string[]) in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, dictionary, hashmap

Could someone tell me the code to get started on Hashmap in C++ for the following case:

I want to have the mapping of (key,value) for (int,string[]).

So, my map should have an int key pointing to a string array of some size. How do I declare and use the hash map for this in C++.

Please help me with this. Thanks in advance

Comment: `std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<std::string>>`

Comment: Or `std::tr1::array` instead of `std::vector` for what it's worth.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a <strike>`std::map`</strike> [`std::unordered_map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/unordered_map/) of `std::vector`s of `std::string`s, but [`unordered_multimap`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/unordered_multimap/) presents a better option in C++. It lets you store multiple items for the same key without managing vectors inside each map entry.

Here is an example of using the map:

```
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    unordered_map<int,vector<string>> mvs;
    vector<string> items1;
    items1.push_back("hello");
    items1.push_back("world");
    vector<string> items2;
    items2.push_back("quick");
    items2.push_back("brown");
    items2.push_back("fox");
    mvs[1] = items1;
    mvs[200] = items2;
    mvs[4].push_back("another_one");
    for(unordered_map<int,vector<string>>::const_iterator iter = mvs.begin() ; iter != mvs.end() ; iter++) {
        cout << iter->first << ":";
        for (vector<string>::const_iterator jter = iter->second.begin() ; jter != iter->second.end() ; jter++) {
            cout << *jter << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

*Edited to mention hash map.*

Comment: Neither of those are hash maps

Comment: @juanchopanza Oops, I missed the "hashmap" part of the question. I am not 100% certain that it is essential, thoug: nested structures like this are often used in languages where class libraries lack multimaps.

Comment: There's also an `std::unordered_multimap`

Comment: @bames53 Fixed, thanks. This has been introduced after I finished building stuff in C++ (which happened about nine years ago), so I'm quite rusty. Thanks again!

Comment: @user356186 I added an example of using the map to add vectors and individual items. Please take a look.